# Save excel file to local storage from Jupyter using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am working with Pandas and I have plenty of Excel files which I need to store in my local storage directly from Jupyter Notebook.

For example,
I create an excel file named "test.xlsx".

Now I want to save this excel file into somewhere in my C:/ drive.

Please help me out with the coding part in python.

Comment: You already created `test.xlsx` in your local drive. What does `save this excel file into somewhere in my C:/ drive.` mean? You already did exactly that. Are you asking how to save to a different path?

Comment: I created a dataframe in pandas and converted it to excel. Now I want to transfer that excel to my C:/ drive.

Comment: The excel file is present in Jupyter and not in my local drive.

Comment: What does `present in Jupyter` mean? Excel is a file. Do you mean you executed your Jupyter notebook on a remote Jupyter server? If you run your Jupyter notebook locally, eg in VS Code or even a local Jupyter server, you can just specify the path you want

Comment: Yes. It's executed on a remote Jupyter server.

Comment: Have a look at this https://skeptric.com/jupyter-download/

Comment: Alternative variaiton because you have a lot of files is to then use tar/gzip to archive the collection of Excel files and then just download that one `.tar.gz` file from the remote Jupyter to your local system. JupyterLab would make you life more easy here as there is a [jupyter-archive extension](https://github.com/jupyterlab-contrib/jupyter-archive) you can install to make directories zippable write from the JupyterLab file navigator via the right-click menu. You'd just have to move your Excel files into a folder/directory first. You could make a directory & then do drag-and-drop for prep.

Comment: This should be performed without any manual effort. Python code should handle this.

Comment: Maybe when I generate the excel, it should be saved directly into local folder